# Filling up a 3x3 matrix under given constraints

Tags: c++, discrete-mathematics

Required to find no of solutions for a 3x3 matrix under Constraints:
1.Every element must be distinct and satisfy condition 1<=value of element<=1000
2.Should satisfy given row's sum ,columns'sum and also diagonals'sum(principal and the other one around)

(We have 8 equations and 9 variables)

I tried converting it in to echolean form and then solve them by trail and error method.But I think there might be a better solution to it by using discrete mathematics tools....!

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the code that you've tried to solve this problem.